# Is toilet paper roll orientation related to personality?

Tags: toilets

According to [Over or under? The science of toilet paper orientation](http://cnet.com/news/over-or-under-the-science-of-toilet-paper-orientation) and [Over or under? The great toilet paper debate](http://dailyinfographic.com/over-or-under-the-great-toilet-paper-debate-infographic)

> ... some studies suggest that the answer is more than coincidence. For
>   instance, people who orient their rolls “over” are more organized and
>   characterized as over-achievers. ... This group represents 70 percent
>   of the people who actually care that much about toilet paper. The
>   remaining 30 percent of this peculiar study group are the “unders”.
>   Characterized as “laid-back”, “artistic”, and “dependable”.

Is there really evidence that one's preference has any correlation with one's personality, and if so, why?

Comment: If the claimed correlation between toilet paper orientation and personality is sufficiently big, then it necessitates in particular a correlation between the character traits mentioned. For example, being "organized" should correlate with being an "over-achiever", and being "laid-back" should correlated with being "artistic" and "dependable".

Comment: @Salbot: Likely, yes. Necessitates? No. A can be significantly correlated to B, and A can be significantly correlated to C without B & C being correlated.

Comment: @Oddthinking: absolutely, note the "If" at the beginning of my comment.

Comment: Well someone called Oddthinking keeps deleting my posts unfortunately, but I think if you look at the sources on that infographic you will find that it is based on a Kimberly Clark survey, and that it is difficult to find any corroborating evidence for these assertions.  I could not find any.

Comment: Worrying about whether things are related to personality is related to personality...